# jquery.form cannot run with two form

Tags: python, file-upload, jquery-forms-plugin, forms, http-post

I'm using jquery form javascript with python.
My site has two form, one for upload a video and one for upload an image(preview pic for that video).
With the code as below, it's run ok if I submit image first then video, but fail vice versa. The POST for image just keep pending like [this screenshot](http://i.minus.com/ieqF2nOHIrj98.jpg)

The code is as below:

**HTML**

```
<div class='wrapper span12'>
    <div class='span6'>
      <h3>Upload video</h1>
      <form id='uploadvideoform' action="{{url_for('video.upload_video')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="myFile" id='myFile' type="file">
        <input type='submit' value="Upload">
      </form>
      <div id="videoresult"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='span6'>
      <h3>Upload thumbnail</h1>
      <form id='uploadimgform' action="{{url_for('video.upload_img')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="imgFile" id='imgFile' type="file">
        <input type='submit' value="Upload">
      </form>
      <div id="imgresult"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
      //ajax upload video
      $('#uploadvideoform').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            $('#videoresult').html('Submitting...  <img src="/static/img/loading-2.gif" />');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var preview_str='';
            var $out = $('#videoresult');
            preview_str += '<video src="http://localhost:5001/static/' + data.video_link +'" controls type="video/mp4" width=480 height=270></video>';
            $out.html(preview_str);
            $('#url').val(data.video_link);
        }
      });

      //ajax upload img
      $('#uploadimgform').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            $('#imgresult').html('Submitting...  <img src="/static/img/loading-2.gif" />');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var preview_str='';
            var $out = $('#imgresult');
            preview_str += '<img src="http://localhost:5001/static/' + data.img_link +'" width=400 />';
            $out.html(preview_str);
            $('#imgPath').val(data.img_link);
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

And the server-side:

```
@video.route('/upload_video', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_video():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        savepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_VIDEO']) + '\\' + current_time
        file = request.files['myFile']
        if not os.path.exists(savepath):
          os.mkdir(savepath)
        savepath = savepath + '\\' + file.filename
        file.save(savepath)
        flash(_("video uploaded successfully!"), "success")
        status = 'success'
        video_link = 'video\\'+current_time+'\\'+file.filename

    return jsonify(status=status, video_link=video_link)

@video.route('/upload_img', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload_img():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'co vo roiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii'
        savepath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_VIDEO_THUMBNAIL'])
        file = request.files['imgFile']
        if not os.path.exists(savepath):
          os.mkdir(savepath)
        savepath = savepath + '\\' + file.filename
        print savepath
        file.save(savepath)
        print 'save xong'
        flash(_("image uploaded successfully!"), "success")
        status = 'success'
        img_link = 'img\\video\\'+file.filename

    return jsonify(status=status, img_link=img_link)
```